# Signed java applet

Tags: java, security, applet, signed-applet

I am creating a socket connection with an unsigned applet to a different host and I'm getting java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

If I sign this applet with either "self-cert" or "CA cert" does the applet gain the permissions to create a socket connection to a different host (not the same host it was downloaded from) and does a security message popup if its been certified by a CA?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't sign the applet, the code which is accessing local resources won't be executed in any way.

If you sign the applet with a self-cert, the enduser would only get a warning message which asks for permission. You however still need to wrap the call inside an [`AccessController#doPrivileged()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html).

```
public void init() {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object> {
        @Override public Object run() {
            // Put your original init() here.
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

If you sign the applet with a $$$-cert, the enduser won't get a warning message.

Comment: There should be no need to use `doPrivileged` if there is no untrusted code on the stack. The warning dialog is much the same whether the certificate is valid or self-signed.

Comment: I guess a cross domain socket connection is untrusted though?

Answer (score 0):

You should see an appropriate dialog for the certificate, unless disabled or that certificate is always accepted. Only if the user agrees is the code given full privileges.

A better approach would be to stick to connecting to only the same-origin host.